# Fit in gnuplot using the logarithm of a column

Tags: plot, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I'm having some troubles fitting a dataset to calculate the Response Time of a Thermometer. So i have my dataset in the form of

```
Time (s) - Temperature (K)
0.4820 295.0772
0.4840 295.0772
0.4860 295.1651
0.4880 295.1651
0.4900 295.1651
0.4920 295.2531
0.4940 295.2091
0.4960 295.2531
0.4980 295.2972
0.5000 295.3412
0.5020 295.2972
0.5040 295.3853
0.5060 295.3412
```

and i want to linearize only the second column by doing the operation

```
y = log($2 - 325.6)
```

so i've written my .gp file this way

```
f(x) = a*x+b
fit f(x) 'termom_COST_SCALED.txt' via a, b u 1:(log($2 - 325.6))

p 'termom_COST_SCALED.txt' u 1:(log($2 - 325.6)) title 'T(t)', 
f(x) title "Linear fit"
```

but someway is not working, even if i plot the graph without the fit

```
p 'termom_COST_SCALED.txt' u 1:(log($2 - 325.6))
```

the outcome is the graph desired, wich i want to make the fit from. Is the syntax of the fit wrong?

```
via a, b u 1:(log($2 - 325.6))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `using` should come before `via`, and you should ignore the header in your data file with `every ::1`:

```
f(x) = a*x+b
fit f(x) 'termom_COST_SCALED.txt' u 1:(log($2 - 325.6)) every ::1 via a,b

p 'termom_COST_SCALED.txt' u 1:(log($2 - 325.6)) every ::1 title 'T(t)',\
  f(x) title "Linear fit"
pause mouse
```

The syntax is now correct.

Your 2nd column is close to 295, which means that `$2-325.6` is close to -31, and its log will be complex :

```
gnuplot> print log(-31)
{3.43398720448515, 3.14159265358979}
```

Is it really what you want?

Comment: Ty so much! That worked for me, but i still don't get the point of `every ::1` and of the command `pause mouse`. I mean, if i have the `#` before the header i don't need that command right? And what about `pause mouse`, is it necessary? Anyway i've found also an error in my code because i don't want to get complex number, but a real one, so i have to change the formula i'm using.

Comment: If you have `#` in your header, no problem. `pause mouse` is just to keep displaying the graph if you use e.g. `wxt`.